# How to split a blockquote tag as gmail does in its editor

Tags: javascript, dom, wysiwyg

Gmail Text Editor splits the blockquote in the textarea when one tries to send an inline reply.

If the reply contains say

`<blockquote>Hai There</blockquote>`

and the user hits enter after "Hai" then the html changes to

`<blockquote>Hai</blockquote><div></div><blockquote> There</blockquote>`

I am trying to achieve this using https://github.com/swilliams/jq-wysihat which is a framework to build javascript text editors..

Comment: Have you tried splitting the string up into words, wrapping each word with block quote and close block quote tags, and inserting open and close div tags in between? Is this all that's going on or am I missing something?

Comment: @swiecki ya.. tried it.. but the problem is the cursor position is lost on replacing. As I am working with a <div> instead of a textarea its hard to set the cursor back to where it was...